# How to prove that the limit of $n/(n+1) = 1$

Tags: sequences-and-series, limits

[image]

So far I have tried rearranging ${n\over n+1}-1 < \varepsilon$ but all I get in the end is $n+1 < \varepsilon$ which doesn't prove anything.

Comment: Actually, what you get by rearranging ${n\over n+1}-1<\varepsilon$ would be $n+1>-{1\over\varepsilon}$, which is (not surprisingly) useless; the reason lies in the fact that $\forall n>0\ \ {n\over n+1}-1<0$. What you must evaluate is $$\left|{n\over n+1}-1\right|<\varepsilon$$

Comment: Hint. If you can find the limit of $(n+1)/n$ then the limit you want is an easy consequence of standard limit theorems. Granted this doesn't use the definition directly, but it may be a help.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Hint:

from $\dfrac{n}{n-1}-1<\epsilon$ you have:

$$\dfrac{1}{n-1}<\epsilon \iff n>1+\dfrac{1}{\epsilon}
$$

So you can chose an integer $N>1+\dfrac{1}{\epsilon}$

Answer (score 0):

$$ \frac{n}{n+1} - 1 = \frac{n}{n+1} - \frac{n+1}{n+1} = -\frac{1}{n+1}$$

Therefore, we need $$\left| a_n - l \right| = \left| -\frac{1}{n+1}\right| = \frac{1}{n+1} < \epsilon.$$

Clearly we can choose $n > 1/\epsilon - 1$ or even just $N$ as the smallest integer greater than $1/\epsilon$.

Answer (score 0):

We have
$$\left|\frac n{n+1}-1\right| = \left|1 - \frac1{n+1} - 1 \right| = \frac1{n+1} $$
Let $\varepsilon>0$, and choose $N$ so that $\frac1N<\varepsilon$. Then for $n\geqslant N$,
$$ \frac1{n+1} < \frac1N < \varepsilon.$$

Answer (score 0):

Let $\epsilon > 0$. Now we have 
$$ \left\vert \frac{n}{n+1} - 1 \right\vert = \left\vert \frac{n+1}{n+1} - \frac{n}{n+1} \right\vert = \frac{1}{n+1} \; .$$
Now chosse $N \in \mathbb N$ big enough, so that $\frac{1}{N+1} < \epsilon$. Then we have for each $n \geq N$
$$\left\vert \frac{n}{n+1} - 1 \right\vert = \frac{1}{n+1} < \epsilon \; .$$